# how to get the tr data-id when click a button

Tags: jquery

hi i have a tr and i have a button inside that tr i want get that tr data-id when i click that button i use this code

```js
$("button").click(function () {
                    var parented = $(".selected").data("id");
                    var clicktr = $(this).parented.data("id");`});
```

```html
`
```

but this is not taken

Comment: `$("tr button").click(function () { $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id'); });`

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not working because the direct parent is `td` not `tr`. Instead of `parent` try `closest` like:

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('data-id');
```